# Pronunciation of "accepted"

Tags: pronunciation, dialects

I just realized that I pronounce 'accepted' more commonly as " uh-sep-ted" than "ak-sep-ted". I'm nowhere near home (Maryland, USA) so I can't listen to see if it is a regional thing. Anyone familiar with this pronunciation possibility? Google seems unfamiliar with it.

Comment: It's not the most common pronunciation, and it's not likely to become the most common pronunciation. That's not because too many people will consider it wrong, but because *except* sort of beat it to the punch. An initial unstressed schwa is just begging for eventual deletion, and *'cept* (or, regionally, *'ceptin'*) is already taken. That will generate some push-back against any tendency to elide the "K" sound in *accept*.

Answer (score 3):

This is a discussion that will take none of us anywhere. What's "correct" and what's not is meaningsless to discuss. If you pronounce it like that, that's fine, but a lot of people would probably say that it's incorrect. According to dictionary.com, the IPA is /ækˈsɛptɪd/, and I don't think the difference is that major between British and American English.

If you're interested in why this is probably a discussion that is not worth having, have a look at [Linguistic description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_description) (the opposite of [Linguistic prescription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription)).

Comment: I am in the /ækˈsɛptɪd/ camp - the first C is hard, the second C is soft.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard many people pronouncing accept as "uh-sept", in India.I don't think it is a regional thing.

There is some discussion ont his topic here http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=64331

The correct one is http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/accept.

Comment: Are you saying that India is ***not*** a region? A pronunciation which only occurs in India and parts of the U.S. should still be called *regional*.

Comment: No, I meant that it is not just native to your region, as it is common here too. And that many in India pronounce it as ak-sept, and hence,  it differs from person to person, and not regionwise.